# Deploying Content Type with Publishing HTML Field by Feature saving content not correctly

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010

I have a problem using a Publishing HTML Field.

The Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Field ID="{987B9BA2-23AB-4E52-99DD-2D59BAA79F4B}" Name="LeftContent" DisplayName="Left Content" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" Type="HTML" Hidden="FALSE"></Field>

<!-- Parent ContentType: Article Page (0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D002da882f450a44abaacff86118ffffaeb"
               Name="Left Content"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{987B9BA2-23AB-4E52-99DD-2D59BAA79F4B}"/>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>

</Elements>
```

In my Page Layout I use ...

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="rchHtmlFldROSTableTwoColumnRight" FieldName="ROSTableTwoColumnRight" runat="server"/>
```

The problem is that when I create a page based on the page layout with this content type and edit the field, SharePoint saves the content not as HTML but HTML Entities. So in not-edit-mode you see the HTML source code like

Hello World

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks!! ;)

Comment: Are you saying that you want the HTML that you place into that field not to be rendered?  Could you clarify the wording and the example you use at the end?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this snippet**

```
<Field ID="0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
       DisplayName="Sample Rich Text Field"
       Name="SampleRichTextField"
       StaticName="SampleRichTextField"
       Group="Sample Fields"
       Type="Note"
       RichText="TRUE"
       RichTextMode="FullHtml"
       Sealed="FALSE" 
       SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Telerik's free RadMossHTMLEditor. The OOTB publishing HTML field does not have cross-browser support. The free control from Telerik works great for me. The controls is called RadEdtior Moss Lite.

Get it from here - http://www.telerik.com/account/downloads/product-versions/single-version.aspx?pmvid=0&pid=543

Dont forget to get the documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Field ID="{987B9BA2-23AB-4E52-99DD-2D59BAA79F4B}"
       Name="LeftContent" 
       DisplayName="Left Content" 
       RichText="TRUE" 
       **RichTextMode="ThemeHtml"** 
       Type="HTML" 
       Hidden="FALSE">
</Field>
```

Thats the solution!!!! ;)